# html/css window resize issue

Tags: html, css

So im fairly new to HTML and CSS and coding in general(C# and C++) and ive been working on a website just for fun. I've mostly learned as i've gone along and im proud of what I have so far even though it isnt much. But I have a problem where whenever I open the site on my laptop which has a smaller screen than my PC or whenever I resize the browser the whole page messes up and text is on top of each other and the background image is smaller with white space all around. I've searched a lot and it seems like everyone has a unique fix for it and none have worked for me. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Trendy</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Images/TitleIcon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h1 class="index-h1">Trendy</h1>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LOG IN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: url(Images/BFG.png);
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

.index-h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Broadway Flat";
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    top: -30px;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 5%;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Broadway Flat";
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px 50px;

    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #e02626;
}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e02626;

    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;

    transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: try adding this blessed tag inside your head element
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: For more context, @doppler 's recommended head element is the default for responsive content, which allows you to establish, via media queries, how your page will respond to different browser screen sizes.

Comment: it's all about responsiveness !  And please **stay away from `position: absolute;`** it simply throws the element from the page flow. I really suggest you  [learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) about `CSS` positioning

Answer (score 0):

You could use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to design your site for smaller screens.
For instance, you can define CSS which only applies if the viewport width is smaller than x.

This example sets the font size to 9pt for a viewport less wide than 400px:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    font-size: 9pt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is supposed to look like but I think you're just needing to supply some responsive code like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   h1.index-h1 {
   max-width: 55%;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
}
```

Generally, avoiding absolute positioning as much as possible is a good idea. Instead of using that, you can use a float for your nav, and as space runs out it will push to the next line.
Or you can use the responsive code above to change it to not float on small device sizes, and instead by displayed block.

If you are instant on using the absolute positioning, consider what you're saying in the code. You're putting a left:60% on the nav, which means you know that the 60% area to the left of it will be blank. So maybe the title should be max-width 60% (or a little less for some padding) and made to shrink a bit as the monitor size shrinks.

Overall, I'd say reconsider your decision to absolute position, and a lot of the answers out there will be more universal to you.

Comment: Okay i see, so do I just place all of my CSS under that? or what parts should i put in the brackets?

Comment: The media query sets the breakpoint (800px wide and smaller in this case) and everything between the curly braces is basically a style sheet that only affects devices within that criteria. You can also have multiple responsive breakpoints, so maybe you want code that affects everything smaller than 800, and additional code that affects only devices smaller than 450... you can do that with 2 separate queries.

Comment: Just keep in mind that those will overlap at those sizes. Responsive can get a little hairy when used in combination with absolute positioning, as you'll find out. The reason is that absolute doesn't take into consideration device sizes. Responsiveness is all about stacking your building blocks into the available space. Absolute does not care about your device size as it doesn't ever try to stack. This is why you'll end up fighting the absolute and why I avoid it except for very small use cases.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error, I realized the text was fine and it was the background that had the issue of not scaling with the browser, so i managed to fix it by doing this:

```html
body {
    background-image: url(Images/BFG.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when i was learning HTML and CSS too it was hard specially the positioning. what helps me is using media queries with this link. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

try using that. and make sure you start on mobile first. if you're using google chrome check dev tools and on top left toggle device to resize the screen size it will help you. then make sure you media queries are min-width since you started at a mobile screen.